# Do android libraries need to be signed?

Tags: android

Pretty much the title says it all. I know Android Application Packages (APK) can and should be signed, but how about an Android library (AAR) file?

I am building a library for internal use and am storing the AAR/Jar file in an internal Maven repo (however the application will be on the play store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer. No. The libraries will be included in each apk and signed by that app's key.